# Custom presented UIViewController changing to fullscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have a view controller presented using `UIModalPresentationCustom` presentation style. I use a custom `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` to present the view controller as a sidebar (so it slides in from the edge of the screen and does not occupy the full screen).

However when I then present another view controller from this one using `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` — and then *dismiss* the full screen view controller, my underlying custom presented controller is suddenly resized to occupy the full screen. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Edit: this is essentially my `animateTransition` method for presenting the sidebar — I've stripped out most of the code to make it readable. Basically it gets the container from the transitionContext, adds and animates the destination view controller's view to the container.

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIView *container = transitionContext.containerView;

    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView *fromView = fromVC.view;
    UIView *toView = toVC.view;

    if( toVC.isBeingPresented )
    {
        [container addSubview:toView];

        //... Animate some new frame for toView            

        //Call [transitionContext completeTransition:YES] on animation completion
    }
    else
    {
        //... Animate fromView out

        //On completion remove fromView from superview

        //Call [transitionContext completeTransition:YES] on animation completion
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Doing a little more research, I notice that the frame of my custom presented view controller's view is being set when the view controller *above* it in the modal stack is dismissed. The following stack trace leads to the frame being set as full screen:

```
0 -[MyCustomPresentedViewControllerView setFrame:]
1 -[UIView(MPAdditions) setFrameOrigin:]
2 -[UIViewControllerAccessibility(SafeCategory) dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:]
3 -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:]
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with the code for your transitioning delegate. Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 7):

Changing the presentation style by assigning:

`viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;`

results in the modal presentation controller occupying a fraction of the screen, the same fraction as the original presented view controller of the `UIPresentationController`.
However, using 
`viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen` 
is better for this case, since his modal controller is full screen.

Answer (score 3):

I am experiencing the same issue. I've tried debugging it using symbolic breakpoints and there seem to be some internal call on some kind of layout manager that does this.

While I wasn't able to "solve" this (it seems to me like a bug in the SDK), I was able to come up with a **workaround that fixes this**. Basically, you have to set the correct dimensions of the presented view at two opportune times. Like this:

> In the view controller that was presented using your custom UIPresentationController, add this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.view.frame = [self.presentationController frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView];
    });
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.view.frame = [self.presentationController frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView];
}
```

And if you are wondering: yes, you do need it to do in two places. Because weirdly enough, when I did it only in the viewDidAppear async block, it got broken (resized to fullscreen) once the animation finished.

Comment: This is working for iOS 9.3.5, as I have tested. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
```

It helped me in iOS 8.1